# Officejs toggle taskpane window on click of ribbon button

Tags: angular, office-js, cpu-word

I am using officeJs to create word add-in using angular framework. I have added ribbon tab with one ribbon button on it and on click on ribbon button i want show and hide the taskpane. So is it possible to toggle the taskpane in officeJS. I have also tried using ExecuteFunction command from manifest but it's not triggering the expected function. If anyone used this ExecuteFunction command in officejs angular project please provide some sample example.

Thanks,
Pooja

Answer (score 1):

You can have a button that opens the task pane just by using the ShowTaskpane Action in the manifest. Users can close the add-in by clicking the "**X**" button on the right end of the title bar. But, as I understand it, you want to be able to hide the task pane while the add-in stays running in the background (as distinct from just ending the add-in session). There is currently no way to do this in a Word add-in. It can now be done in Excel. For details, see [Show or hide an Office Add-in in a shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/show-hide-add-in).

With Word, if you want the task pane out of the way, you can instruct your users to resize it or just drag it completely out of the Office window.